# Azure blob storage backup

Tags: azure, backup, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I wonder is there's an inbuilt way in azure to backup a blob account, or just a container if that can't be done. Looked into azure backup service but can't find the option for doing it, just options to backup VM.

Alternatively I can write my custom back up strategy, but not sure if it's the case that I can't find that option inbuilt.

Thanks,

Comment: this seems close:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11561844/what-is-the-best-way-to-backup-azure-blob-storage-contents

Comment: Yes, saw it but that's why I would say is custom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no blob backup facility. You'll need to make your own backups (e.g. making copies of blobs, either to the same storage account or a different one). You *can* take snapshots, but as @Gaurav points out in comments, snapshots are tied to the original blob, so if you delete the original, you delete the snapshots.

I answered a similar question regarding backups and Table Storage, as well, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43746454/272109).